# Azure Web Sites: NetworkInterface.GetIsNetworkAvailable() always returns false

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I have an Azure web site and the call to NetworkInterface.GetIsNetworkAvailable() always returns false. Has any one else run into this behavior?

Comment: You probably did the right thing in also asking at http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/windowsazuredevelopment/thread/5a8efa69-9769-4418-b460-cf7c411de026 . Why do you require calling GetIsNetworkAvailable in this scenario? Third-party software?

Comment: Yes, we have third party software. It seems it was blocked by the azure team.

Comment: I added Microsoft's reply as an answer to complete this topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated (2013-03-29) by MSFTs Jim Cheshire in [this thread](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/windowsazurewebsitespreview/thread/5a8efa69-9769-4418-b460-cf7c411de026#af2b3659-2934-4c1a-97ef-28f867b23c2e) this API is blocked in WAWS.